# Use ugettext and ugettext_lazy in the same file in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm working on translating a Django project. Nearly everything works fine. I just can't get django to collect strings marked with something else than `_` (underscore).

Let me explain a bit more : so as the doc stipulates, I'm using `ugettext` and `ugettext_lazy`. I think I've understood well enough why and where I should use `ugettext_lazy` but in some models I can use `ugettext` at one place and `ugettext_lazy` at another place (e.g. because the first is in a function requested only when a user makes a request and the second is part of the model definition (e.g. a field name) ).

So I'm doing it like this

```
from django.utils.translations import ugettext as _
from django.utils.translations import ugettext_lazy as _l

class MyModel():
    myfield = CharField(..., verbose_name=_l("My Field"), ...)
    # Here it is needed to use the lazy version

    def edit_my_model():
        msg = _('You are going to edit this model')
        # For performance, I prefer to use the non-lazy version when I can
        ....
```

Everything works fine as long as I have my .po files with all the translations. But my problem is to have those translations in the .po files. Indeed when I run `django-admin makemessages` to collect all marked string it only collect the "non-lazy" ones (the ones marked with a `_`) and even remove the ones I had previously added manually.

Does anyone know to tell django-admin to also collect ugettext_lazy marked strings or will I be forced to have only `ugettext_lazy as _` (and replace every non lazy ones) in my files ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `_l` alias.

Just import `ugettext_lazy` without any alias:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

short_description = _("Price")

caption=ugettext_lazy("Copy link")
```

---